# Is it possible to recover data deleted from a list?

Tags: list, custom-list

Is there any kind of versioning for lists, or is an entry gone forever when deleted?

Answer (score 3):

It could be restored from the recycle bin. Please check article below for broad understanding versions and recycle bin.

Note that versions protect you restore previous version of item/document whereas recycle bins help you restore deleted item/document.

[Plan to protect content by using recycle bins and versioning (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263011.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Recycle bin works in SharePoint 2010. If you're on SharePoint 2007, you're out of luck. Restore the entire site from backup and then grab the data you need.

Comment: I'm curious about your SP2007 comment. List items are recycled in SP2007, right?

Comment: Thanks for calling me out on this. I had a relapse... 2007 introduced it, I was thinking of 2003... tough getting old.

Comment: Right there with you.